# Does class need parenthesis after class name, when we call a method within this class

Tags: python, tensorflow

Which one is right

A

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss = cost)
```

or

B

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer.minimize(loss = cost)
```

FYI, the screenshot from AdamOptimizer of TensorFlow page:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A is right

`optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = 0.01).minimize(loss = cost)`